# android commonsware endless adapter fetch content before list reaches the end

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac, cwac-endless

I am using the endless adapter from https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

This works great for me, but I am looking to fetch rows not when the users reach the end, but rather before. In other words, I prefer that the user will not see the pending view at all or at least minimize this situation.

I did not find yet the option in this adapter to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: As is noted on the project page, this project is retired.

Comment: I have not gone looking for one.

Comment: @CommonsWare why did you retire it?